# How to Insert an Animated gif in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show animated gif in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935232/show-animated-gif-in-java)

How can I insert an animated gif image in Java?

I have already looked at different answers and question. But when I code this, it doesn't show the gif animated.

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("yourFile.gif");
Image image=ImageIO.read(new File("yourFile.gif"));
```

In the end, I use the method `drawImage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use a JLabel (Stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935232/show-animated-gif-in-java), go give him credit if this is what you needed.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    URL url = new URL("<URL to your Animated GIF>");
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Animation");
    f.getContentPane().add(label);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Is flashes a bunch unlike the original gif. Any idea why?