# Understand an gif is animated or not in JAVA

Tags: java, java-7

I have a gif image and I would like to be able to detect whether the gif is an animated gif or not using JAVA. This question is about detection rather than displaying the gif.

I see that MIME type of animated gif isn't different of static gif.

How I can do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935232/show-animated-gif-in-java

Comment: You should be able to manually parse the file header.  Have a look at [this thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t146605-identifying-animated-gifs.html).

Comment: @bknopper not a duplicate as this question is not about showing, but about detecting an animated GIF.

Comment: @bknopper: Robin Krahl is right, I don't want to show it, i want to detect it, before asking this question i see the another one you mentioned but doesn't help.

Comment: ok, the question is a little bit ambiguous :P I proposed an edit.

Comment: The question is not properly spelled but also not ambiguous: "understand" is very different from "display"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need an ImageReader. if size is 1 its not animated, everything above is animated.
Check this out:

```
public Snippet() {
        File f = new File("test.gif");
        ImageReader is = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix("GIF").next();  
        ImageInputStream iis;
        try {
            iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(f);
            is.setInput(iis);  
            int images= is.getNumImages(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
}
```

Comment: I'd just recommend closing the stream in a `finally` block, to add completeness to the answer.

Comment: or doing like this:
``try(ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(f) {``
when using Java > 6