# How to detect if a given image file is an animated GIF in Android

Tags: java, android, image, animation, gif

'm writing an image editor.

I do not support editing animated gifs, so when the user selects an image I need to show an error message if that image is an animated gif.

So given a file path, how can I distinguish between a static and an animated gif?

I checked the question [Understand an gif is animated or not in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221528/understand-an-gif-is-animated-or-not-in-java) but it does not apply for Android since the ImageIO class is not available.

Note: I only need to know if is animated, so I'd like the fastest approach

Comment: http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/identifying-animated-gifs.146605/

Answer (score 5):

The code below works for me:

Check by using the image http url.

```
URL url = new URL(path);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len = 0;

while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
}

inputStream.close();
byte[] bytes = outStream.toByteArray();

Movie gif = Movie.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
//If the result is true, its a animated GIF
if (gif != null) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Or check by select file from gallery:

```
try {
    //filePath is a String converted from a selected image's URI
    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len = 0;

    while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    fileInputStream.close();
    byte[] bytes = outStream.toByteArray();

    Movie gif = Movie.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    //If the result is true, its a animated GIF
    if (gif != null) {
        type = "Animated";
        Log.d("Test", "Animated: " + type);
    } else {
        type = "notAnimated";
        Log.d("Test", "Animated: " + type);
   }
} catch (IOException ie) {
   ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Where is the `Movie` class taken from?

Comment: Its a android default class, check this out: [link]https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html

Comment: This class was deprecated in API level 28.
Prefer AnimatedImageDrawable.

Comment: Not only gif but it also detects the webp images if it is animated. So it will return true even it is not gif but the animated webp image

Answer (score 3):

Summarize answers.. in Kotlin

```
private fun checkIfGif(file: File) : Boolean {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(file)
            val drawable = ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(source)
            if (drawable is AnimatedImageDrawable) {
                return true
            }
        } else {
            val movie = Movie.decodeStream(file.inputStream())
            return movie != null
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        // not handled
    }
    return false
}
```