# How to add GIF image in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, animated-gif

i want to draw a gif image in my panel,the problem is that my code draws jpg images fine but i does not draw gif images.This is how my code looks like.

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
Image image;

public DrawingPanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    image = new  ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Hp\\Downloads\\loading.gif").getImage();
}

@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}
```

Comment: Did you even try to google or search on this site? [First hit on google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935232/show-animated-gif-in-java). "Animated Gif Java"

Comment: Why is this using custom painting for the image instead of displaying it in a label (which should automatically animate it)?  1) See also [Show an animated BG in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10836832/418556) 2) `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);` should be `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);`

Comment: I am using paintComponent because i have to draw a grid.and i want gif image in the background, like flow free game

Comment: Then see the details in 'Show an animated BG in Swing'!

Comment: i did and it helped,thanks @andrewthomson

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedImage image;
image = ImageIO.read(new File("image name and path"));
```

Use [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);    
}
```

Comment: image is visible,but it's frozen.No animation