# Store animated GIF image in a Java program

Tags: java, image, animation, gif

In a Java program you can store images like .png, .jpg and such in a `BufferedImage`. I don't think it works for animated gif images as it seems to lose its animation.

Currently I get normal images like:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(images.get(x)));
String type = images.get(x).substring(images.get(x).length() - 3, images.get(x).length());
ImageIO.write(image, type, new File(title + "/" + filename));
```

Where `images` is a `String[]` of URLs.

As for gif's I'm getting them by:

```
byte[] b = new byte[1];
URL url = new URL(images.get(x));
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
DataInputStream di = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(title + "/" + filename);
while (-1 != di.read(b, 0, 1) && downloading)           
    fo.write(b, 0, 1);
di.close();
fo.close();
```

But I want to store them in the program and write them to a file another time. How do I store a GIF without writing it to a file but while keeping its animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in storing the gif in memory, and not in having it display from the java program. You could write the data you've received into a [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) rather than a `FileOutputStream`, and then take the resulting byte array and write that to a `FileOutputStream` at a later time.

If you would like to display the animated gif, you might want to check out the top answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935232/show-animated-gif), although the first comment on the answer seems to be having a problem similar to yours.

Comment: How would I go about writing the data from the `DataInputStream` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Comment: @CodedApple You should be able to do it by just replacing the line `FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(...);` with `ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`. Then after you have written the gif to the stream, you can fetch the bytes by calling 'toByteArray'. Then, when you want to write those bytes into a file, just open up a new `FileOutputStream` and write the byte array into it.